Unable to view linked server tables list in SSMS object explorer
I'm using SQL2022
I have a linked server to another SQL server, security is set with a defined username/password.
My issue is that when logged into the server with a standard account I cannot see a list of the tables/views on my linked server within the object explorer.
I can query the linked server just fine, but cannot expand the tables tree to see what tables are available.
If I log into the server with my SA account, I can expand the tree and see all the tables and views on the linked server.
What permission do I need to set on my standard login to be able to view the tables in the object explorer.

Could you share the linked server options under the "security" options?

Maybe you need to add a account mapping between local server and linked server, Try to run a system stored procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin do so. Code like this
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
     @rmtsrvname=N'linked_remote'  --The linked server name in your SSMS linkedserver list
    ,@useself=N'False'    -- must be false
    ,@locallogin=N'standard'  --Your standard account name that login local server with SSMS
    ,@rmtuser=N'sa'   -- remote server's account username you linked
    ,@rmtpassword='sapassword' --remote server's account password you linked

Or, you can do this with SSMS, follow the document.
